# How can i push the new value inside existing array where value match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have one array where I would like to find matching values inside this array whenever there is change in input field (This input field comes with test_id value and the input value).

Below is the existing array:

```
[{ result: null, test_id: 1 }, { result: null, test_id: 2 }]
```

Below is the result when there is change in the input:

```
[1, 45]
```

From the result, first one is the test_id and the second is the value for result.

Expected result change in input:

```
[{ result: 45, test_id: 1 }, { result: null, test_id: 2 }]
```

the value inside the existing will change with corresponding to its test_id

Here is my code

```
<q-input
  v-model="form.test_input[test.test_id]"
  @change="onChangeResult([test, form.test_input[test.test_id]])"
/>


onChangeResult (data) {
  const a = this.form.test_results
  a.map(function (test) {
    test.data = data.filter(function (a) {
      return data[0].test_id === test.test_id
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map through the results and replace the one item that matches. `map()` does not mutate the original array so you need to assign it to a value. If we use `let` on the original variable, we can update it through this function. To assign it, I'm using `{...spread}`

```js
let a = [{ result: 45, test_id: 1 }, { result: null, test_id: 2 }]; // this.form.test_results 
const onChange = (data) => {
  a = a.map(test => test.test_id == data[0].test_id ? { ...data[0], result: data[1] } : test);
  console.log(a)
}

onChange([{test_id: 2}, 10])
onChange([{test_id: 1}, 12])
```

Comment: The way you passed values in `data` tripped me up a little, so let me know if this needs adjusting.

Comment: data[0] will contains the test_id and data[1] will contains the result value, which will be for test_id

Comment: the value is updated correctly, but whenever there is change in input, the previous array comes empty

Comment: Hmmm. not sure I understand, but I updated my answer with a snippet. Can you take a look and tell me where it's not working the way you'd like?